# How can I use firebase without the emulator?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, emulation, firebase-tools

I am learning firebase and I checked this tutorial regards the authentication. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbuSx1yEgV8&t=502s). In this video, the emulator seems to be essential, however I want to communicate with the server. How do I do it? If I do not initialize the auth emulator ( by removing the connectEmulator() function) I just get the error 'auth/network-request-failed'.

```
    const firebaseConfig = {
        //...
    };
    
    const user = {
        email: 'user@test.me',
        password: 'test1234'
    }

    function func() {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, user.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
            // ..
        });         
    }
```

As you can see from the minute 7:37 of that video, I am getting his issue! So I assume I am following the wrong approach. Can someone help me? I would be really grateful.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

### You *should* be able to authenticate with the server.

The emulator is optional. Personally I rarely use it, and essentially always use the real online Firebase server. However there are many steps before you are able to authenticate with the server.

#### Step 1. Check you have copied the configuration correctly

Go to this link, but replace PROJECT_ID with your actual project Id:

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/PROJECT_ID/settings/general/

Check that you have correctly copied the value of this into your app code from that page. If you have not "added an app", you may need to click "Add app", to get this config to display.

```
const firebaseConfig = { 
    ... blah blah ... 
};
```

#### Step 2. Check that you have enabled a "Sign-in provider"

Go to this link (again PROJECT_ID should be replaced by your project Id):

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/PROJECT_ID/authentication/providers
```

At least one of the providers needs to be switched on, like so:

[image: At least one provider is switched on]

#### Step 3. Your code looks good.

I assume you have set up `auth` correctly - we can't see that in the snippet above.

Please paste into your question the exact error message you are seeing on the console, as text.

You might want to intensify the debugging as follows:

```
function func() {
    console.log(`user: ${JSON.stringify(user,null,2)}`)
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, user.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log(`userCredential.user: ${JSON.stringify(userCredential.user,null,2)}`)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
    });         
}
```

A small thing, but I suggest avoiding using the same variable name, `user`, for two different things. Javascript will keep them separate, but we as programmers sometimes will get muddled when looking back at the code.

#### Step 4. Make sure you have authorised the domain you are using.

Go to:

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/PROJECT_ID/authentication/settings

Make sure you have authorised the domain from which you are "calling" the Firebase server.

[image: Only localhost is authorised]

If your app is running on "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost", you might need to add that IP address too. Or if you have deployed, the deployed domain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Everything is correct, in fact when I use the emulator it works. However I still have this issue.

Comment: And step 3? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Once I call the function I get the object 'user', and after a minute I get 'Error (auth/network-request-failed)'

Comment: Update: I tried to register a new user and the function worked correctly. It was also visible in the users list. Then I deleted that user, and the onAuthStateChanged() function returned (after minutes, I do not know why does it take so much time) the deleted user.

Comment: The register function does not work anymore. I do not know how to do!

Comment: A. First thing to do is to list these console.log outputs in the Question itself, not in the comments. That way they can be seen by everything. 

B. Copy and paste a complete chunk of text. Do not paraphrase or give a summary, because that makes people fear that there might be missing information, and make it less worthwhile to volunteer their help.

C. In this pasting, make it obvious what the user Id you created previously was, and what the new user Id you are trying to create is.

D. Do not say "does not work any more". Put the exact error message, in full, clearly on the question.

Comment: I am sorry, thank you for giving me these informations.

Comment: I was having some issues with the register function, as (when I was running the app with android emulator (see the UPDATE in the question)) almost everytime I recieved the auth-network-request-failed error. Then, I randomly tried to register (with the android emulator) an user, and for some reason it worked. After that, I tried to reload the app and re-call the register function, but that time I got another time the error auth-network-request-failed. I do not know why did it work one time. Probably the android emulator connection is not so reliable, according to firebase services.