# How to use firebase realtime database with authentication turned on but without emulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**Context:**
I have a react web application that uses firebase realtime database. Till now, authentication was not turned on, so after `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` .. where `firebaseConfig` was taken from the app's firebase console.., I would do something like this:

```js
const myRef = ref(db, '/myresource')
unsubscribeFirebaseListener = onValue(audiosRef, (snapshot) => {
 const data = snapshot.val()
 console.log("my data:", data)        
})
```

where `db = getDatabase()`... (`getDatabase` is from `firebase/database`)
and I would be able to print the resource in the console. After enabling authentication (email/password authentication), I am unable to get that onValue callback to fire on any change in myresource. The authorization rules are simple:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Also, I wish to bypass the whole emulator setup because the data is being populated externally by another service in the actual firebase realtime database and I need to work with this data even when I am running the app locally (in localhost).

**Problem:**
If I turnoff the emulator, I am stuck at the authentication step.
this is how I do authentication:

```js
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
 // Signed in
 console.log("logged in: ", user)
}).catch((error) => {
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;
 console.log("No user: ", errorCode, errorMessage)
});
```

this is the error I see in console:

> index.ts:136     POST http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<my_application_key> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

You can see that `:9099` is the default emulator port. The `signInWithEmailAndPassword` seems to invoke the local emulator even when I don't have `connectAuthEmulator()` anywhere in my code and have no emulator running.

I was able to get around that error by using connectAuthEmulator. But then I was unable to get data from the protected route (myresource). I would like to know how to do this authentication without emulator and also be able to access data at myresource.

I see a similar post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75042468/how-can-i-use-firebase-without-the-emulator) and I checked that all 4 steps are OK. But I am still not able to get authentication working without emulator. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some questions to help diagnose the issue: What's in your `firebase.json`? Are you using the RTDB emulator at all? Any environment variables that might cause the SDK to connect to the emulator?
Your rules don't include a path which seems to be required, see: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is `.firebaserc` file needed in the project root whenenver authentication is turned on. With this structure:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "your_project_id"
  }
}
```

It appears that authentication imports provided by firebase like `signInWithEmailAndPassword` need this file to properly connect with the cloud firebase instance. Note that this is required even if you have a `firebaseConfig.js` file like so in your project:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import {getDatabase} from "firebase/database"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getDatabase()
export const appAuth = getAuth(app)
```

Its possible to stumble across this issue if you have integrated RTDB first (without authentication turned on) and then later turned authentication on. Because the former does not require `.firebaserc` file.